# getting more data from nginx prometheus exporter

Tags: nginx, prometheus, exporter

I'm using [nginx Prometheus exporter](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter), but the amount of data that its metrics are very little, I want to get information of access.log and error.log too, like how much 200, 404,...
what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

The richier metrics are only available with NGINX Plus which comes at a premium. Unless you want to modify the source code, additional metrics are only available through the log file.

If you are already aggregating logs, say with an elasticsearch, you can use the [related exporter](https://github.com/braedon/prometheus-es-exporter) to extract metrics.

If not, there are solutions either from dedicated project such as the [nginxlog-exporter](https://github.com/martin-helmich/prometheus-nginxlog-exporter) or generic solutions such as [mtail](https://github.com/google/mtail) where you can write your own rules.

Finally, there is an intermediary solution which is the official one on Prometheus site: [extracting metrics with lua](https://github.com/knyar/nginx-lua-prometheus). This is maybe the more robust solution but it comes at the cost of the setup.

It is hard to make a suggestion. It all comes to your time/skill/money budget and the usage you are making of nginx. It you are using it as a proxy, [envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/) is gaining traction.

In fact, your question is a bit broad but worth an answer because the basic monitoring available is really poor for the widespread usage nginx enjoy (IMNSHO)